# How to do dynamic if statement in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join

I'm working on a forum and, like in every forum, there are threads and responses. These are the tables I use in the database to store them:

```
post
------------
id
user_id
time
type
effective_id

thread
------------
id
update_time
text
response_number
deleted

response
------------
id
container_id
text
deleted
```

The `post.type` is an `enum('thread', 'response')`, and the `post.effective_id` has to match a `thread.id` or a `response.id` according to what the `post.type` indicates.

As you can see, I'm factorizing everything that the threads and responses have in common.

---

Here's the problem I've encountered: I want to determine if a given post was deleted (having it's `id` as information) in a **single query** and **without moving the `deleted` field to the post table**.

These would be the queries I'd use if I knew beforehand if the given id belongs to a thread or a response.

```
SELECT thread.deleted
FROM post INNER JOIN thread ON post.effective_id = thread.id
```

or

```
SELECT response.deleted
FROM post INNER JOIN response ON post.effective_id = response.id
```

But how can I say in SQL, "`if the post.type is thread then INNER JOIN with thread and get the deleted field, if post.type is response then INNER JOIN with response and get the delete field.`"? I'd need some kind of dynamic "if"

Is this even possible to do with the specified conditions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the case in the below query :

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN post.type = 'thread' THEN thread.deleted
WHEN post.type = 'response' THEN response.deleted
ELSE 'default'
END
FROM post 
LEFT JOIN thread ON post.effective_id = thread.id
LEFT JOIN response ON post.effective_id = response.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two left joins:

```
SELECT IFNULL(thread.deleted, response.deleted) AS deleted
FROM post
LEFT JOIN thread ON post.effective_id = thread.id
AND post.type = 'thread'
LEFT JOIN response ON post.effective_id = response.id
AND post.type = 'response'
```